# Mocking SQLite database calls for DJango ORM pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

Below is the code from one of my django view which uses django ORM to fetch data, however running the same from pytest gives error:

> FAILED tests/test_views.py::TestViews::test_trendchart_view -
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'metricname'

```
metrics = Metrics.objects.all()
metric = metrics.filter(metricid=metric_id).first()
metric_name = metric.metricname
```

Looking at the error it seems that metric is None. Any idea how can I mock this call to return some dummy object?

Below is my test case for reference:

@pytest.mark.django_db

```
class TestViews:
    def test_trendchart_view(self):
        kwargs={'event_id':1, 'ar_id':1, 'tcid':1, 'activemenu_id':1, 'metric_id':1}
        path = reverse('trendchart', kwargs=kwargs)
        request = RequestFactory().get(path)
        response = treandchartsummary(request,None,**kwargs)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: `.first()` returns a `None` if no `Metrics` objects satisfy the `.filter(...)` condition.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, that's what I mentioned in question but real problem is how ca  mock it in pytest?

Comment: I do not really see why that is necessary. In your test you can create a model object with `Metrics.objects.create(metricid=some_id, ...)`. You should not test if Django itself is correct, that is up to the developers of Django: typically the tests check if the logic in the views, forms, models, etc. is correct.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Where do I need to write this model object code? in fixture?

Comment: you can do that in the `setUp` methd of your test.